# Python objects returned more than once by gc.get_referents()

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm using `gc` module (Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10) to analyze object references.

Starting with the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(gc.get_referents(a,b))
```

Obtaining the result:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

It seems that an object is referenced more than once from the list returned by `gc.get_referents()`. Using `set` in the following way:

```
print(set(gc.get_referents(a,b)))
```

I get something like the union of the list of referents of `a` and `b`:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I'd like to know if this is the correct way to get the correct number objects referred to by a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all objects that are referred to without duplicates, yes,

```
set(gc.get_referents(a, b))
```

will give you those.